# Do I need to sanitize Wordpress search query?

Tags: search, security

I submit search data to a custom page `searchi.php`

```
<?php
    //
    $search_variables = $_GET['s']. '+' .$_GET['cat'];

    //This sends http post to url without curl
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:http://localhost/wordpress/?s=$search_variables");
    exit;

?>
```

I know `wp_query` sanitizes variables for me, so I should not worry about it. But it is better to ask than be sorry, is there any way this would compromise security?

I noticed echoing variable `$search_variables` with `<div></div>` inserted through search form works, so should I do something about it?

Answer (score 11):

No. WordPress sanitizes the search query.

To use the sanitized search query, use [**`the_search_query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query) to echo, or [**`get_search_query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_search_query) to return, the search query.

#### Edit

Based on your edit:

- Don't use `$_GET['s']`. Use **`get_search_query()`**.
- Don't use `$_GET['cat']`. Use **`get_the_category()`**.
- All `$_GET` and `$_POST` data should be *assumed to be inherently unsafe*, and should be sanitized/validated accordingly.

Comment: But, searchi.php is not part of wordpress, and 'cat' is not a real category, I'm using relevanssi plugin to match complicated strings. So I need this extra outside page that just puts two input content into 1 and submit it back to wp search. Honestly I don't see problem with my current implementation, I do use GET but the contents of GET goes to original wp search query anyways, so where is the risk? More detail would be appreciated on the matter.

Comment: "*I do use GET but the contents of GET goes to original wp search query anyways*" - I'm not sure how to answer any more clearly. If you want *assumed* safe, use `get_search_query()`; if you use `$_GET` data, you should *assume* that it is unsafe and treat it accordingly.