# Does WordPress sanitize arguments to WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, security, sanitization

This is a very straight-forward question, but it's important and I can't find anything definitive in the docs.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63664/do-i-need-to-sanitize-wordpress-search-query) asks a similar question for the `'s'` parameter, specifically. I want to know if WordPress validates/sanitizes parameters for **any** of the other parameters. For example, do the terms in a `tax_query` get sanitized automatically?

**Clarification:**
This is a technical / engineering question about specifically what the WP_Query class does with particular parameters. Several recent answers offer philosophical advice and general best practices regarding validation/sanitization. But that's not what this question is about. My goal is compile facts rather than opinions.

Comment: Based on a quick scan of the WP_Query class in core, it appears that some params are sanitized but some are not.  The class is defined here for a more complete look at it: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php

Comment: @jdm2112 Ahh. The plot thickens. If it is a mixture of sanitized and not, then that's even more dangerous! I took a quick look also but didn't spot any that _weren't_ sanitized. I might start a bounty to come up with a definitive list.

Comment: Sanitised for what purpose? Any core functions that interact with the database will be properly prepared/escaped to avoid SQL injection, if that's your concern.

Comment: @Jacob security was my primary concern

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually a good question. Of course user input cannot be trusted, but also sanitizing the same value twice "just in case" isn't the best solution for a problem.

The only real answer to this question can be given by looking at the code and following what goes on.

And after reading it for a few hours, here is what I can say about it:

> WP Query sanitizes the values but it doesn't do it all in one place. Values are being sanitized before they are actually used. It's a very organic and *on the go* approach. Also, not all of the values are sanitized, but in those cases a prepared statement is used for the SQL query.

### Let's get into detail

So, what happens when we do:

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The WP_Query class constructor checks if the `$args` is an empty array or not. And if it's not, it will run its `query()` method passing the `$args` array (which is at this point called `$query` array).

```
$this->query($query);
```

The `query()` method calls the `init()` method which unsets possible previous values and sets new defaults.

Then it runs [wp_parse_args()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_args/) on the `$args` array. This function does not sanitize anything, it serves like a bridge between default data and input data.

The next call is for the `get_posts()` method, which is in charge of retrieving the posts based on the given query variables.

The first thing that is called inside the `get_posts()` method is the `parse_query()` method, which starts by calling the `fill_query_vars()` method (this one makes sure that a list of default keys are set. The ones that are not, get set with an empty string or empty array depending on the case).

Then, still inside the `parse_query()` method, the first santization takes place.

`p` is checked against [is_scalar()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php) and cleaned with [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Also [absint()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/absint/) is used on the following values:

```
page_id
year
monthnum
day
w
paged
hour
minute
second
attachment_id
```

Also, a `preg_replace('|[^0-9]|'...)` is run on `m`, `cat`, `author` to only allow comma separated list of positive or negative integers on these.

For other values at this point, only the trim() function is used. This is the case for:

```
pagename
name
title
```

After this, the method starts checking what type of query we are running. Is it a search? An attachment? A page? A single post? ...

If a `pagename` is set then we call (without sanitizing the value) `get_page_by_path($qv['pagename'])`. But checking that function source we can see that the value is sanitized with [esc_sql()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/) **before it's used for a database request**.

After that, we can see that when the keys `post_type` or `post_status` are used, they are both sanitized with [sanitize_key()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_key/) (Only lowercase alphanumeric characters, dashes, and underscores are allowed).

For the taxonomy related parameters, the `parse_tax_query()` method is called.

`category__and`, `category__in`, `category__not_in`, `tag_id`, `tag__in`, `tag__not_in`, `tag__and` are sanitized with [absint()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/absint/)

`tag_slug__in` and `tag_slug__and` are sanitized with [sanitize_title_for_query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_for_query/)

At this point the `parse_query()` method is over, but we still are inside the `get_posts()` method.

`posts_per_page` is sanitized.

`title` is being used unsanitized but with a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). You may find this question interesting: [Are prepared statements enough to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Then we have `post__in` and `post__not_in` that are being sanitized with [absint()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/absint/).

And if you keep reading the code and pay attention, you will see that all the keys are actually being sanitized before they get to touch a SQL statement or a prepared statement is used instead.

So, to answer your original question:

**Does WordPress sanitize arguments to WP_Query?**

It does sanitize most of them but not all. For example, `pagename`, `name` and `title` are only "cleaned" with the [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function (does not return SQL safe values!). But for the values that are not sanitized, a prepared statement is used to perform the database request.

### Should you trust this?

Well, in this specific case I would prefer to go for the possibly **redundant** just presanitize everything approach before you throw it into the query.

Me too, as an engineering student, I would love a solid yes or no answer. But note that the WordPress codebase has evolved in a natural way so it's just like nature: *messy*. It does not mean it's bad. But messy means that there could be an unseen edge-case where somebody could potentially sneak in with a bomb. And you can prevent that by just doubling your guards!

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if I have to sanitize user input for **any** of the other parameters.

You should never trust user input, and therefore always sanitize and/or validate it, regardless of whether it is already done in core. Your code, your responsibility.

As stated in the [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/), for example:

> **Don’t trust any data.** Don’t trust user input, third-party APIs, or data in your database without verification. Protection of your WordPress themes begins with ensuring the data entering and leaving your theme is as intended. Always make sure to validate on input and sanitize (escape) data before use or on output.

You could also check [the code of the `WP_Query` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L18) for yourself. A quick search for sanitization-related code, e.g. [WordPress's built-in sanitization functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/), reveals that at least some sanitization takes place. But if I were you, I'd better be safe than sorry, and write and test my own sanitization and/or validation logic.

Comment: `You could also check the code of the WP_Query class` --> this is basically the question that I'm asking, and the reason I offered the bounty. I've updated the question to make this very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple rule that I learned a long time ago when studying for fullstack development.

If it's data/code that you didn't write yourself, always always always sanitize and validate it.

Never trust data from anywhere, really, not even from established companies like facebook, google, github.

Even if you think that wordpress will sanitize the information you should always do your own sanitation and validation.

Never go like, it's just a simple newsletter registration form with only a email field, whats the worst that can happen? STOP!

When you hear about data leaks that exposed hundreds or thousands (in the best case) of user data, it sometimes happens because some developer just said, what's the worst that can happen, or even worse, was not aware of the (basic) security measure he should implement to prevent such a leak.

Always sanitize and validate!

> EDIT

Ok, so after reading your question again I think I know what you mean now.

For example, the `tax_query`, after looking in the wordpress github repo I found that everything related to `tax_query` is being handled by `class WP_Tax_Query`, among other things in handles the sanitization and validation of the data that you passed into `tax_query`.

Now, if `class WP_Tax_Query` handles `tax_query` im sure that if I would keep looking in the wordpress repo I would have found more classes or methods that handle sanitization and validation of other properties.

I think your best bet it to go to [WP_Query](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d6cc4f1aecaafc21f5c40b707fdba240cc37564b/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php) in the wordpress repo and doing a deep dive into all the properties that you use in order to see how `WP_Query` handles each one of them

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question that I'm asking. I've updated the wording in the question in the hopes of making it very clear.